# How do you test a Vue.js modal component with Jest?

Tags: testing, vue.js, jestjs

I have a vuejs modal component that shows the modal of team members (avatar, full_name & description). I need to test it.

teamMembers.js looks like :

```
    <template lang="pug">
      .col-lg-4.col-md-6.team_member_wrapper
        a(href="javascript:;"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#TeamMemberModal" @click="$emit('clicked', item)" )
          .team_member
            .team_member_image
              img(:src="item.avatar")
            .team_member_name {{item.full_name}}
            .team_member_status {{item.status}}
            .team_member_shadow
    </template>git status
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "TeamMember",
      props: {
        item: {},
      }
    };
    </script>
```

my test code is :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import  TeamMember  from '@/components/TeamMember.vue'
import {  mount } from '@vue/test-utils'


const wrapper = mount(TeamMember, {
  context: {
    props : {
        item : {
            avatar : 'path/to_image.png',
            full_name: "Robocop"
            }
        } 
    }
});
```

I need to validate that the template generated the correct html
 - while  the Wrapper must contain a Vue instance. I did this :

```
wrapper.setProps({ avatar: 'path/to_image.png' }),
expect(wrapper.vm.avatar).toBe('path/to_image.png'),


wrapper.setProps({ avatar: 'Robocop' }),
expect(wrapper.vm.full_name).toBe('Robocop')
```

I run my test, got the following result :

FAIL  tests/unit/specs/TeamMember.spec.js

> ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> [vue-test-utils]: mount.context can only be used when mounting a functional component
>
>    9 |        item : {
>   10 |            avatar : 'path/to_image.png',
> > 11 |            full_name: "Robocop"
>      |                                            ^
>   12 |            }
>   13 |        } 
>   14 |    }
>
>   at throwError (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:11:9)
>   at createInstance (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:2847:5)
>   at mount (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:5639:18)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/specs/TeamMember.spec.js:11:36)
> ```

what mistake in my code, & how can I correct it ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The options you are passing should be on the root level of the object, and props data is set with the `propsData` option:

```js
const wrapper = mount(TeamMember, {
  propsData: {
    item: {
      avatar: 'path/to_image.png',
      full_name: 'Robocop'
    }
  }
})
```